# Helm delete all releases

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying find a way to delete all deployed releases in Helm.

It appears that Helm [does not support](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-delete) deleting all releases, with `--all` or otherwise.

Would there be another way to delete all Helm releases in one command?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

To delete all Helm releases in Linux(in Helm v2.X) with a single command, you can use some good old bash. Just pipe the output of `helm ls --short` to `xargs`, and run `helm delete` for each release returned.

`helm ls --all --short | xargs -L1 helm delete`

Adding `--purge` will delete the charts as well, as per @Yeasin Ar Rahman's comment.

`helm ls --all --short | xargs -L1 helm delete --purge`

On Windows, you can delete all releases with this command, again, with `--purge` deleting the charts as well.

`helm del $(helm ls --all --short) --purge`

**Update:** As per @lucidyan comment, the `--purge` arg is not available in Helm v3.

Comment: there might be some times where you want to delete even the deleted charts then you can use it like this


`helm ls --all --short | xargs -L1 helm delete --purge`

Comment: Is "-L1" option really required? Seems to be working without it too.

Comment: @demisx: The `-L1` is not required. This arg is for max lines, which defaults to one anyway, so in this case it is not needed.

Comment: `-L` option is not in busybox.

Comment: Note than `--purge` flag is not available in Helm 3

Comment: For newer version `helm ls --all --short | xargs helm  uninstall`

Answer (score 31):

**For helm 3** you have to provide namespaces so there is an `awk` step before `xargs` :

`helm ls -a --all-namespaces | awk 'NR > 1 { print  "-n "$2, $1}' | xargs -L1 helm delete`

This results in commands like:

`helm delete -n my-namespace my-release`

Comment: This is the correct and cross-platform answer which takes namespaces into account.

Comment: This answer that takes care of all deployment across namespaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

**`helm delete $(helm ls --short)`**

Description:

`helm ls --short` gives a list of releases ids.

`helm delete id1 id2 id3` deletes releases with ids: `id1`, `id2`, `id3`.

So combining them we get:
`helm delete $(helm ls --short)`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me in a powershell cmd window:

```
helm del $(helm ls --all --short) --purge
```

Comment: `helm del $(helm ls --short --deleted) --purge` to purge all DELTED chart.

Comment: For Windows PS this is indeed the correct answer, the accepted answer does not work on Windows.

Comment: `helm del $(helm ls --all --short |grep test) --purge` to delete and purge only deletes release starting with test name.

Answer (score 3):

I regularly delete all releases in Helm too, so I thought it'd be useful to make a Helm plugin for it.

Install:

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/tedmiston/helm-delete-all-plugin --version 0.0.3
```

*(You may be able to omit the `--version x` part on newer versions of Helm.)*

Usage:

```
helm delete-all
```

https://github.com/tedmiston/helm-delete-all-plugin

Comment: Repo does not exist anymore

Answer (score 3):

If you use `xargs` in the `alpine` container then you will get the following error;

`xargs: unrecognized option: L`

So, you can use the following command to **delete all releases** in a **specific namespace** for the **helm v3**.

`helm uninstall -n <namespace> $(helm ls --short -n <namespace>)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good plugin for delete all helm releases from all namespaces (The previous plugin in this post doesn't work for me) .
Install:

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/BarelElbaz/helm-delete-all
```

usage:

```
helm delete-all
```

you can provide more flags such as `--deletePersistent` for delete PVCs
or skipping a specific namespace by `--except-namespace`

Answer (score 1):

To delete all releases in a particular namespace

```
helm ls  --short  -n <<namespace>> | xargs -L1 helm uninstall  -n <<namespace>>
```