# How to delete all resources from Helm list by one command?

Tags: resources, command, kubernetes, command-line-interface, kubernetes-helm

List installed `Helm` resources:

```
$ helm ls
NAME                REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART               NAMESPACE
myresource1         1           Fri Jan 19 10:00:02 2018    DEPLOYED    my-chart-1.0.0      default
myresource2         1           Sat Jan 20 10:01:01 2018    DEPLOYED    my-chart-2.0.0      default
myresource3         1           Sun Jan 21 10:02:02 2018    DEPLOYED    my-chart-3.0.0      default
```

There is a way to delete one resource:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#helm-delete-deleting-a-release

Is it possible to delete all resources one time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Helm delete all releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817818/helm-delete-all-releases)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way of doing it, but you can use some good old bash

```
helm list --short | xargs -L1 helm delete
```

Remember to add the `--purge` flag if you want to delete everything related to the release.

Comment: As of helm v3 `--purge` is default behavior. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59210923/6106886

Answer (score 8):

In short and only with helm commands you can use:

`helm delete $(helm list --short)`