# What is the purpose of helm delete --purge

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Using helm is super cool, but what is the purpose of using `helm delete --purge`

I can see the [doc](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_delete.md) says:`remove the release from the store and make its name free for later use`

So what is the purpose of saving the name and not releasing it with `helm delete`?

Comment: As an aside, you can purge all deleted releases with `helm delete --purge $(helm ls --deleted -q)`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When you do `helm delete $RELEASE_NAME` it deletes all resources but keeps the record with $RELEASE_NAME in case you want to rollback. 
You can see removed releases via `helm ls -a`. 
Whereas `helm delete --purge $RELEASE_NAME` removes records and make that name free to be reused for another installation.

Comment: note: helm3 removed this flag and this answer is no longer valid in helm3+

Comment: In Helm 3+, it looks like `helm uninstall` fully deletes and purges releases, unless you specify the `--keep-history` flag: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helm-uninstall-uninstalling-a-release

Comment: lol, I just realized another response already clarified this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59210923/2585632

Answer (score 40):

Just to note as of helm v3 `--purge` is default behaviour. You no longer need the flag

If you want to keep any history (aka the behaviour of helm 2.x's `helm delete` without the `--purge` flag) you now need to use `--keep-history`  eg `helm delete nginx-ingress --keep-history`

Answer (score 3):

Recently they've finally managed necessity of `--purge` by replacing `helm delete` with `helm uninstall`. 
There appears it works fine now

Comment: Looks like `delete` and `uninstall` are aliased.