# How to delete(uninstall) helm chart on specific resource

Tags: redis, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have installed [`redis`](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/helm-package-manager). The default given name to me is `plinking-narwhal`. Now I would like to install a service with my assigned name. But first I want to remove the existing one. I had tried deleting them without success.

```sh
$ kubectl get all
NAME                                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/plinking-narwhal-redis-master-0                1/1       Running   0          12m
pod/plinking-narwhal-redis-slave-9b645b597-2vh82   1/1       Running   7          12m

NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes                      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    15m
service/plinking-narwhal-redis-master   ClusterIP   10.109.186.189   <none>        6379/TCP   12m
service/plinking-narwhal-redis-slave    ClusterIP   10.99.122.12     <none>        6379/TCP   12m

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/plinking-narwhal-redis-slave   1         1         1            1           12m

NAME                                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.apps/plinking-narwhal-redis-slave-9b645b597   1         1         1         12m

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
statefulset.apps/plinking-narwhal-redis-master   1         1         12m
master $ helm delete stable/redis
Error: invalid release name, must match regex ^(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])+$ and the length must not longer than 53
master $ helm delete --name plinking-narwhal stable/redis
Error: unknown flag: --name
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You probably need:

```
$ helm delete redis
```

or if you completely want to remove the release:

```
$ helm delete redis --purge
```

`stable/redis` is not allowed as an expression because of the slash(`/`)

If you'd like to see the name of the releases you can simply run:

```
$ helm list -aq
```

Comment: add `--purge` to the delete command if you want to reuse the release name

Comment: Unknown flag purge whatever i'd put it

Comment: @holms since Helm 3, there is no `--purge` option as [purging is now the default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59210923/992887)

Answer (score 18):

`Helm delete` command is renamed to `helm uninstall`. So you probably have to use:

```
helm uninstall redis
```

More info at - https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_uninstall/

Answer (score 0):

**helm delete networkpolicy -n namespace_name**

release "networkpolicy" uninstalled