# Helm delete all release older than some date, updated before some date or if the app version is lower than

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I delete release older than, for example, the 1st of October?
I mean updated before the 1st of October.
Alternatively, delete all releases with the app version lower than _.

Helm ls output:

> |NAME|REVISION|UPDATED                 |STATUS  |CHART   |APP VERSION|NAMESPACE|
>   |myapp| 8     |Fri Sep 27 17:27:20 2019|DEPLOYED|myapp.85|85         |default|

The following command deletes just one.

> helm delete relase_name

The following is not a great solution as well

> helm delete relase_name1 relase_name2 relase_name3

**Note1:** I don't want to delete all. There is an explanation of how to do that over here [Helm delete all releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817818/helm-delete-all-releases) and I don't want to do that. However, I assume I need to use bash for this task.

**Note2:** I have already read documentation it is not that big. There is nothing over there about filtering.
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-delete

**Note3:** I have already looked into helm sources, I am not 100% sure but It doesn't look like it is possible https://github.com/helm/helm/tree/master/pkg/helm

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command bellow kind of worked for me, it is far from perfect solution but at least it helped me :

```
helm ls -d -m 25 --namespace default --short | xargs -L1 helm delete
```

**helm ls** - lists all of the releases.
**-d** orders by date.
**-m** maximum number of releases to fetch (so I take 25).
**--namespace default** - Show releases within a specific namespace, this option helped me to filter my app releases.
**--short** - this option limits output of the command to release names only.

**The solution is not perfect and *I hope that someone can provide a better solution.***

Comment: Yeah, I definitely feel like we should put in a PR for `helm list` to enable us to list charts that were updated after a certain time. I imagine that this would work similarly to the time arguments for `find`.

Answer (score 7):

*Assuming Helm version 3+*

You can use `jq` and `xargs` to accomplish this:

**Question 1**, to delete releases that were last updated before `$TIMESTAMP` (in seconds):

```
helm ls -o json | jq -r --argjson timestamp $TIMESTAMP '.[] | select (.updated | sub("\\..*";"Z") | sub("\\s";"T") | fromdate < now - $timestamp).name' | xargs -L1 helm uninstall
```

> `sub("\\..*";"Z") | sub("\\s";"T")` converts the date format
>   Helm uses in their output to ISO 8601.

**Question 2**, to delete releases with an app version older than `$VERSION`:

```
helm ls -o json | jq -r --argjson version $VERSION '.[] | select(.app_version | sub("\\.[0-9]$";"") | tonumber | . < $version).name' | xargs -L1 helm uninstall
```

> `$VERSION` should be major or major.minor only (i.e. `2` or
>   `2.1`). don't use a patch number.

**Question 3**, to delete releases by their initial deploy date, you'll have to parse the contents of the `helm history RELEASE` command for each release.

I won't solve this one, but it would look something like:

```
loop over helm ls
  get release name
  get first entry of helm history for that release
  pass to jq and process like the answer for question 1
```

Relevant Links:

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sub(regex;tostring)sub(regex;string;flags)
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates
- https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_history/

Comment: What a great answer. Great to learn that jq has these advanced ways of filtering results.

Comment: I get "jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson"

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample my script for this:

```
DT=$(date --date="1 weeks ago" +%s)
LIST=$(helm list -A -d --short -f '-[0-9][0-9][0-9]+')
for nm in $LIST
    do 
        DU=$(helm list -A -d -f $nm | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/UPDATED//' )
        DD=$(date --date="$DU" +%s)
        if (( "$DT" >= "$DD" ))
            then
                NAMESPACE=$(helm list -A -f $nm | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/NAMESPACE//' )
                NAME=$nm
                echo ---START---
                echo $NAME
                echo $NAMESPACE
                echo ---END--- 
                echo -e '\n'
            fi
    done
```

You have variables that is needed for you into the loop, and can do that you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).