# How to delete helm release older than 1 month

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I know I can list all helm release using  `helm ls --tiller-namespace <tiller-namespace>`

What command I can use for deleting helm release old than 1 month ?

Comment: Duplicated question. Answer could be found there https://stackoverflow.com/a/58301975/2110663

Comment: @Panoptik that answer does not answer my question actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below shell script, that takes all the list of releases and it's last deployed in seconds using the `helm ls` and `jq` utility command; which then loops through the releases list and does some subtraction on the number of days it has been deployed and then deletes the releases which are older than a month. By month, I've just given `30 days`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#Store the release names alone for a specific tiller.
helm_releases=(`helm ls --short --tiller-namespace "kube-system"`)
#Store current date
CURRENT_TIME_SECONDS=`date '+%s'`
for RELEASE in ${helm_releases[@]};
do
  LAST_DEPLOYED_SECONDS=`helm status $RELEASE --tiller-namespace "kube-system" --output=json | jq -r '.info.last_deployed.seconds'`
  SEC_DIFF=`expr $CURRENT_TIME_SECONDS - $LAST_DEPLOYED_SECONDS`
  DAY_DIFF=`expr $SEC_DIFF / 86400`
  if [ "$DAY_DIFF" -gt 30 ]; then
    echo "$RELEASE is older than a month. Proceeding to delete it."
    helm delete --purge --no-hooks $RELEASE
  fi
done
```

You can still define your own logic on top of this by calculating the seconds differences for a month.
Please note that I've explicitly mentioned the `--tiller-namespace`. You can use that if you're releases are deployed in a namespace which uses tiller other than `kube-system`.