# Helm uninstall delete resources in all regions

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Was working with helm charts to deploy kubernetes resources on a particular cluster. 
I have services deployed on three regions us-west-1, us-east-1, us-west-2.
When I do a helm uninstall will it delete resources in all regions?

Comment: How you have installed these services ?

Comment: Using helm charts

Comment: `helm uninstall` will undo what `helm install` did, but without knowing more about your particular setup it's a little hard to say more.  "Region" isn't a core Kubernetes concept.

Comment: How you have used helm to install services in different regions ?

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68944293/10025322